# How do I add a job to cron?

Tags: shell, cron, crontab, putty

So, here's what I did:

1. Logged in as `root` via Shell
2. Typed `crontab -e`
3. Typed `*/30 * * * * /path_to_website/cronjobs/cron.php`

And now what? How do I save it? I just closed Putty and then logged back in as `root`, typed `crontab -l`, and no crons were added. So I must have screwed up somewhere.

I'd appreciate if someone could give me more detailed information.

And weirdly enough, when I log in as `root` and type `crontab -e` and I try to enter `*/30 * * * * ...` it doesn't work right away (it only lets me type `/`). I first have to press like every key that's on my keyboard.

Comment: If you have root access to this machine, you owe every user on it the courtesy of learning [how to use vi](http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/vi.html).

Comment: Well, good thing I'm the only user on that machine. Haha.

Comment: Well then, you owe it to yourself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, I think `crontab -e` uses `vi`. So, after you've made your changes, hit Escape and type `:wq` then press Enter.

Comment: Perfect! It totally worked now. Appreciate your help, Christopher.

Comment: Also to start inserting text use the i key.

Answer (score 3):

You can hit shift-zz to close and automatically save the file.

Comment: Nice, I like that!

Comment: Similarly `ZQ` is equivalent to `:q!`

Answer (score 2):

If your cron editor is vim, you would `ESC` and type `:wq`

Answer (score 0):

As the correct answers here state, you need to save before crontab will parse your file and try to install your new edits.  crontab, like many UNIX apps, checks the EDITOR environment variable for an editor, or then defaults to vi.

You can make it a bit easier by changing the editor you use:

```
EDITOR=kate crontab -e
EDITOR=gvim crontab -e
```

you get the idea....